# Check plugins/packages for deprecated apis in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, dependencies

I want to check my dart packages for deprecated apis. Particulary if they are using `UIWEBVIEW`. Is there a way to search the packages similar to `grep -r UIWebView node_modules/*`in npm?